# Pfaffian generalization

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, matrices, determinants, pfaffian

The identity
$$\left|
\begin{array}{cccc}
 x & y_1 & y_2 & y_3 \\
 z_1 & 0 & a & b \\
 z_2 & -a & 0 & c \\
 z_3 & -b & -c & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right|=\left(-a y_3+b y_2-c y_1\right) \left(a z_3-b z_2+c z_1\right)$$
is clearly a generalization of
$$\left|
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & y_1 & y_2 & y_3 \\
 -y_1 & 0 & a & b \\
 -y_2 & -a & 0 & c \\
 -y_3 & -b & -c & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right|=\left(-a y_3+b y_2-c y_1\right)^2.$$ The same is true for similar $2n\times 2n$ matrices. Are these Pfaffian generalizations known?

Comment: This is just the polarization identity $2Q(x,y) = Q(x+y,x+y) - Q(x,x) - Q(y,y)$ applied to both sides of the second equation, together with the fact that an odd-dimensional Pfaffian vanishes to get rid of the term on the diagonal.